# ManyToMany Spring JPA как сохранить

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa

У меня есть два класса - пост и теги к нему

```
@Data
@Entity
@Table(name = "articles")
public class Article {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    private String title;
    private String text;

    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private ArticleStatus status;

    @Column(name = "author_id")
    private Long authorId;

    @Column(name = "created_at")
    @CreatedDate
    private Date createdAt;

    @Column(name = "updated_at")
    @LastModifiedDate
    private Date updatedAt;

    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinTable(name = "tags_articles",
            joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "post_id", referencedColumnName = "id")},
            inverseJoinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "tag_id", referencedColumnName = "id")})
    private Set<Tag> tags;
}
-----------------------------------
@Data
@Entity
@Table(name = "tags")
public class Tag {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    private String name;

    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "tags", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private Set<Article> articles;

    {
        articles = new HashSet<>();
    }
}
```

Пользователь, создавая пост, может пометить его тегами, а может и не помечать. Как мне сохранить в бд и пост, и теги, связанные с ним? названия всех тегов в дб уникальны. Кое-что я пыталась сделать:

```
//save all tags if they exists
if (articleDto.getTags() != null) tagRepository.saveAll(articleDto.getTags());
        articleRepository.save(article);
```

Но при запросе на то, чтобы достать пост, все ломается

```
2021-01-13 16:04:55.264  WARN 16036 --- [nio-8082-exec-4] o.h.e.loading.internal.LoadContexts      : HHH000100: Fail-safe cleanup (collections) : org.hibernate.engine.loading.internal.CollectionLoadContext@2f7a7e6d<rs=HikariProxyResultSet@1356434174 wrapping Result set representing update count of -1>
2021-01-13 16:04:55.312 ERROR 16036 --- [nio-8082-exec-4] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Handler dispatch failed; nested exception is java.lang.StackOverflowError] with root cause

java.lang.StackOverflowError: null
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:1016) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:174) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.defineClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:800) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.findClassOnClassPathOrNull(BuiltinClassLoader.java:698) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClassOrNull(BuiltinClassLoader.java:621) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:579) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:178) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521) ~[na:na]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ClientPreparedStatement.executeQuery(ClientPreparedStatement.java:1020) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.22.jar:8.0.22]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.ProxyPreparedStatement.executeQuery(ProxyPreparedStatement.java:52) ~[HikariCP-3.4.5.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariProxyPreparedStatement.executeQuery(HikariProxyPreparedStatement.java) ~[HikariCP-3.4.5.jar:na]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.extract(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:57) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.25.Final.jar:5.4.25.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.plan.exec.internal.AbstractLoadPlanBasedLoader.getResultSet(AbstractLoadPlanBasedLoader.java:390) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.25.Final.jar:5.4.25.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.plan.exec.internal.AbstractLoadPlanBasedLoader.executeQueryStatement(AbstractLoadPlanBasedLoader.java:163) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.25.Final.jar:5.4.25.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.plan.exec.internal.AbstractLoadPlanBasedLoader.executeLoad(AbstractLoadPlanBasedLoader.java:104) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.25.Final.jar:5.4.25.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.collection.plan.AbstractLoadPlanBasedCollectionInitializer.initialize(AbstractLoadPlanBasedCollectionInitializer.java:87) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.25.Final.jar:5.4.25.Final]
    at org.hibernate.persister.collection.AbstractCollectionPersister.initialize(AbstractCollectionPersister.java:710) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.25.Final.jar:5.4.25.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultInitializeCollectionEventListener.onInitializeCollection(DefaultInitializeCollectionEventListener.java:76) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.25.Final.jar:5.4.25.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.service.internal.EventListenerGroupImpl.fireEventOnEachListener(EventListenerGroupImpl.java:102) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.25.Final.jar:5.4.25.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.initializeCollection(SessionImpl.java:2163) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.25.Final.jar:5.4.25.Final]
    at org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection$4.doWork(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:589) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.25.Final.jar:5.4.25.Final]
    at org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection.withTemporarySessionIfNeeded(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:264) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.25.Final.jar:5.4.25.Final]
    at org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection.initialize(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:585) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.25.Final.jar:5.4.25.Final]
    at org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection.read(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:149) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.25.Final.jar:5.4.25.Final]
    at org.hibernate.collection.internal.PersistentSet.hashCode(PersistentSet.java:458) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.25.Final.jar:5.4.25.Final]
    at com.nastyabakhshyieva.blog.entities.Article.hashCode(Article.java:12) ~[classes/:na]
    at java.base/java.util.HashMap.hash(HashMap.java:339) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.HashMap.put(HashMap.java:607) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.HashSet.add(HashSet.java:220) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.AbstractCollection.addAll(AbstractCollection.java:352) ~[na:na]
    at org.hibernate.collection.internal.PersistentSet.endRead(PersistentSet.java:355) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.25.Final.jar:5.4.25.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.loading.internal.CollectionLoadContext.endLoadingCollection(CollectionLoadContext.java:239) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.25.Final.jar:5.4.25.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.loading.internal.CollectionLoadContext.endLoadingCollections(CollectionLoadContext.java:224) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.25.Final.jar:5.4.25.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.loading.internal.CollectionLoadContext.endLoadingCollections(CollectionLoadContext.java:198) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.25.Final.jar:5.4.25.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.plan.exec.process.internal.CollectionReferenceInitializerImpl.endLoading(CollectionReferenceInitializerImpl.java:154) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.25.Final.jar:5.4.25.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.plan.exec.process.internal.AbstractRowReader.finishLoadingCollections(AbstractRowReader.java:260) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.25.Final.jar:5.4.25.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.plan.exec.process.internal.AbstractRowReader.finishUp(AbstractRowReader.java:211) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.25.Final.jar:5.4.25.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.plan.exec.process.internal.ResultSetProcessorImpl.extractResults(ResultSetProcessorImpl.java:96) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.25.Final.jar:5.4.25.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.plan.exec.internal.AbstractLoadPlanBasedLoader.executeLoad(AbstractLoadPlanBasedLoader.java:105) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.25.Final.jar:5.4.25.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.collection.plan.AbstractLoadPlanBasedCollectionInitializer.initialize(AbstractLoadPlanBasedCollectionInitializer.java:87) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.25.Final.jar:5.4.25.Final]
    at org.hibernate.persister.collection.AbstractCollectionPersister.initialize(AbstractCollectionPersister.java:710) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.25.Final.jar:5.4.25.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultInitializeCollectionEventListener.onInitializeCollection(DefaultInitializeCollectionEventListener.java:76) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.25.Final.jar:5.4.25.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.service.internal.EventListenerGroupImpl.fireEventOnEachListener(EventListenerGroupImpl.java:102) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.25.Final.jar:5.4.25.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.initializeCollection(SessionImpl.java:2163) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.25.Final.jar:5.4.25.Final]
    at org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection$4.doWork(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:589) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.25.Final.jar:5.4.25.Final]
    at org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection.withTemporarySessionIfNeeded(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:264) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.25.Final.jar:5.4.25.Final]
    at org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection.initialize(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:585) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.25.Final.jar:5.4.25.Final]
    at org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection.read(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:149) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.25.Final.jar:5.4.25.Final]
    at org.hibernate.collection.internal.PersistentSet.hashCode(PersistentSet.java:458) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.25.Final.jar:5.4.25.Final]
    at com.nastyabakhshyieva.blog.entities.Tag.hashCode(Tag.java:9) ~[classes/:na]
    at java.base/java.util.HashMap.hash(HashMap.java:339) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.HashMap.put(HashMap.java:607) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.HashSet.add(HashSet.java:220) ~[na:na]
```

Еще один способ состоял в том, чтобы сделать все то же самое, но только еще и добавить к тегам в список этот пост:

```
if (articleDto.getTags() != null) {
tagRepository.saveAll(articleDto.getTags());
articleDto.getTags.forEach(t -> t.add(article))
}
 articleRepository.save(article);
```

Но тут так же вылазит ошибка о переполнении стека

А если пытаться сохранить исключительно посты, то падает с ошибкой о том, что нужно вместе их сохранять

Answer (score 0):

Все нормально, просто не стоило доверять hashCode и equals от lombok (они друг на друга ссылались)